# implement Infinite Scrolling on click of button in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper

From publication i am setting an argument called `limit`. and this is my controller

```
MainPageController = BaseController.extend({

findOptions: function() {
return {sort: {createdAt: 1}};
},

waitOn: function() {
return Meteor.subscribe("allCars",5,this.findOptions());
},

data: function(){
 return {cars: Cars.find({},this.findOptions() )};
}
});
```

in my Template i have a button on click of which i want to load the next 5 records. my helpers are in different file. how can i implement this infinite scrolling. please help

**Publication**

```
Meteor.publish('allcars', function(limit){
return Jobs.find({}, {limit: limit});
});
```

then i am setting a default session variable for it

```
Template.jobsList.onCreated(function(){
    Session.setDefault("carsLimit",5);
});
```

after this in the helper i am very confused and its a whole lot of mess i have done.

and this is my template

```
<div class="col s12">
  <ul class="cars-list">
    {{#each allCars}}
    <li>
      {{> carItem}}
   </li>
   {{/each}}
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteorpedia has [a piece on infinite scrolling](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Infinite_Scrolling) which is, in my opinion, the simplest implementation for infinite scrolling in meteor. It's dead simple.

In your case (pressing a button) it would be even simpler, as you have no need to listen to scrolling events. Just increment the `itemsLimit` session variable every time your button is pressed. (no need for a `showMoreVisible()` function in your case)

```
Template.jobsList.events({
  'click #showMoreResults': function (e, t) {
    Session.set("carsLimit",
            Session.get("carsLimit") + 5);
  }
});

Template.jobsList.helpers({
  'moreResults': function() {
    return !(Cars.find().count() < Session.get("carsLimit"));
  }
});

Template.jobsList.onRendered(function(){
  Session.set("carsLimit",5);
  this.autorun(function () {
    Meteor.subscribe("allCars", Session.get('carsLimit'));
  });
});
```

And on your template:

```
<div class="col s12">
  <ul class="cars-list">
    {{#each allCars}}
    <li>
      {{> carItem}}
   </li>
   {{/each}}
   {{#if moreResults}}
   <li id="showMoreResults">More cars!</li>
   {{/if}}
  </ul>
```

Comment: i tried doing it but still i am not able to get it.

Comment: Can we see your code for publication, template and template helpers?

Comment: i updated publication and template and little code. my other  code is a mess. can you please explain with this code

Comment: Updated my answer with suggestions

Comment: I am having an error with this.i guess this is a dumb question but as i am new in meteor it might help me understand it better, can you please explain do i need to subscribe it two times? i am already subscribing it from the controller.

Comment: Yes you can subscribe to a publication as many times as you want. This second subscription will be called every time the `carsLimit` session variable is updated, so that the limit sent to your publication will be updated on every button press. Also, make sure your publication and subscription have the same names. In your example they're called respectively "allcars" and "allCars"

Comment: Glad to hear that. And now for a little puzzle: this solution will work perfectly in cases where your collection is not a multiple of 5. (your increment value) If your total collection has exactly 10 cars, your button will still appear after one click, even though 10 cars are already on the list. Can you figure out how to avoid that?

Comment: Hint: the trick is to extract one car less for your template data than the limit you subscribed to.

Comment: That can work, if your subscribed to a higher limit than `carsLimit`. Remember that on the client side, `Cars.find()` can only give you as many cars as the ones you have subscribed to.

Comment: ok. there's one more thing i noticed now. when i am navigating to a different page and when i come back to the car listings page it is preserving the state.i.e after i have loaded all the records by clicking loadmore button and then if i navigate to other page and come back to the main page its still showing all records instead of the limit which we set it to(5 records in this case). i guess its because of Session. how can i get it back to same state as just showing 5 records?

Comment: There are many ways to do so. An easy way is to reset your `carsLimit` to 5 in the `onAfterAction` function of your jobsList route.